# Making an object(with camera) move passively

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, virtual-reality

I'm creating a Vive VR Passive VR experience, where your in a space ship and without any controls, it moves passively through the whole solar system. It's not AI, there will be a predetermined destination.

My question: How to make on object move passively?(A.K.A Space Ship with cameras)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a starting point, and a destination point, then [Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) between them. The examle in the unity documentation has a example for your exact question.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform startMarker;
    public Transform endMarker;
    public float speed = 1.0F;
    private float startTime;
    private float journeyLength;
    void Start() {
        startTime = Time.time;
        journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startMarker.position, endMarker.position);
    }
    void Update() {
        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
        float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endMarker.position, fracJourney);
    }
}
```

You would attach that script to your "Spaceship" root object, you would then make the player a child of the spaceship so it will move with the ship as it goes along it's route.

Comment: The idea is to make the space ship "fly" in a arc type of movement. I will try using this, at least it will be a good start point. This is something like those VRs with roller coasters except on a spaceship in space.

Comment: In that case you may want to [use a animation](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation) to perform the movement. You can set each place you want to stop at as keyframes and let it figure out for you how to get between each location.

Answer (score 0):

[Path Magic](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/47769) on the Asset Store could do it all for you, and you probably don't have to code anything.